# Two boot system images in cisco router

Tags: cisco, router

on my router I have two boot lines:

```
boot-start-marker
boot system flash c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M3.bin
boot system usbflash0:c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M3.bin
boot-end-marker
```

I have a feeling that there should be only one line, and it should be like this:

```
boot-start-marker
boot system usbflash0:c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M3.bin
boot-end-marker
```

Please confirm if am I right?
Or it should be set up differently?
My current dir is as following:

```
router010#dir
Directory of usbflash0:/


    1  -rw-    85237324  Dec 20 2018 13:51:34 -07:00  c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M3.bin
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have several `boot system` commands, the router tries them in order, which is the normal way to specify images with a failover to older versions or for different source devices.  In your particular case, if those two files are the same, you can delete one of them.

> Enter several boot system commands to provide a fail-safe method for booting your router. The router stores and executes the boot system commands in the order in which you enter them in the configuration file. If you enter multiple boot commands of the same type—for example, if you enter two commands that instruct the router to boot from different network servers—then the router tries them in the order in which they appear in the configuration file.

From https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/ffun_r/frf010.html